# How to count observations of a specific value according to some conditions in pandas dataframe -python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this kind of dataframe :

```
Tag     Error
4       10
3       8
2       11
3       7
4       14
3       5
4       6
2       8
```

I would like to calculate only the number of observations for values in the 'Error' column strictly smaller than 10 according to each 'Tag'.

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
Df.groupby('Tag')(['Error']<10).value_counts()
```

Comment: `df[df['Error'].lt(10)].groupby('Tag')['Error'].count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. I think something like the following should work:

```
df[df['Error'] < 10].groupby('Tag').value_counts()
```